# What could be causing imac to not access certain sites?

Tags: macos, dns, blocking

My iMac has security off, firewall, antivirus etc. Yet somehow there are a few websites it cannot access that my macbook can. On the same network. Tried different browsers. Checked the hosts file. Nslookup even yielded the same on both computers. I'm using Google DNS.  I'm at a loss. Where else can I look that this might be blocking me?

Comment: Please clarify what “cannot access” means. The exact error message is very important.

Comment: Can't ping. Can't Access the webpage. Both time out.

Comment: Anyone? This issue is really annoying. Someone must have an idea.